# Github Actions - Multiple branches - AWS S3 static site

Tags: github, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm working with Github Actions to push my site to S3 for continuous integration. Its working for my main branch. Was looking to have it push the site branch code to my Quality Assurance bucket.

Main branch -> live production S3 bucket
QA branch -> QA S3 bucket

name: Upload Website

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Deploy static site to S3 bucket
      run: aws s3 sync . s3://PROD_Bucket --delete
```

I tried the following but it fails. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the logic of the yaml.

```
name: Upload Website

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    aws-region: us-east-2

- name: Deploy static site to S3 bucket
  run: aws s3 sync . s3://PROD_Bucket --delete

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - QA

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Deploy static site to S3 bucket
      run: aws s3 sync . s3://QA_Bucket --delete
```

Is there an easy way to say "when commit is made to QA, go to bucket_2. When commit is made to main, go to bucket_1"?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you just need a second yaml under root/.github/workflows/

It would just be the second branch you want to whitelist. Duh.